# Load a Font using Typeface.createFromFile(File file) in Android-Library project

Tags: android, file, android-library, typeface

I created a library project for Android and I'd like to load a font for text using something like Typeface.createFromFile().

I chose Typeface.createFromFile(File file) method, because Android Lib do not support AssetManager, so I can't use Typeface.createFromAsset(..).

I was thinking use Raw folder of android resources. But I only get InputStream of the file with context.getResources.openRawResource(R.raw.comic_sans) and I can't use it in Typeface.createFromFile(File file).

Another alternative is trying to use [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), but I don't know if is possible to move a file to there in project-time.

If I do not find a solution, I can still design the lib for using the AssetManager of the Application that is using this lib. But I really don't want it.

Example what I want to do:

```
Paint textPaint = new Paint();
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromFile("comic_sans.ttf");
textPaint.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: did you find a solution?? if so can you please post it.

Comment: @i8taken, I didn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the question is how to set something as a specific font?

Well here is how:

1. Make a folder in the `app > src > main` directory of your project and call it "assets"
2. Download the specified `TrueType font file` that you want to import (This is the font that you want to import)
3. Move the specified `TrueType font file` into the assets folder
4. In your java class, type this in the onCreate method :

Example code:

```
Typeface test_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getResources().getAssets(),"example_font.ttf");
TextView exampleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
exampleTextView.setTypeface(test_font);
```

Lastly, import anything that is missing

Hopefully this helps

Comment: No, it is not a solution. My project is a Lib and it do not support AssetManager.